# "Assertion Failed: undefined must be a subclass or an instance of Ember.View, not " with no useful info

Tags: ember.js, assertion

I started getting this error, but all attempts to debug the reason failed.

The whole info is like this:

```
Ember.assert    @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:3940
readViewFactory @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:39239
viewHelper  @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:7521
inline  @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:7948
render  @   VM4480:884
render  @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:44625
EmberRenderer_createElement @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:40279
Renderer_renderTree @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:8768
ensureChildrenAreInDOM  @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:41922
_ensureChildrenAreInDOM @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:41885
invoke  @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:854
flush   @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:919
flush   @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:724
end @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:149
(anonymous) @   ember-1.10.0.debug.js:552
```

which doesn't help me at all. Nothing is pointing me to the element that is failing, and at the same time a lot of ember elements fail to render.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or how to find the exact problematic problem?

(Installed `Ember inspector` which also doesn't help me at all.)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of dumping stuff I figured out that I have elements (`{{view ...}}`) which behavior is not `described` in the JS file for that page. So I changed them to some custom `{{#view ...}} ... {{/view}}` elements with identical functionality, but the code about them is described in the JS files on the page.

That was the reason, and it's pretty sad `Ember` doesn't show such stuff in a better way.

Comment: By the way, views are no longer a recommended best practice in Ember (starting in 2.0 they were removed, although there was an add-on that supported them until 2.4).  So would suggest you begin refactoring away from them in your app ...

Comment: Yea, I agree : )... the thing is that the code is legacy :) and in the near future we'll completely refactor the whole Single Page App ... but for now we have to deal with the stuff we already have ...